# How to define the option to save the cookies at FireFox (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

In Firefox, there are cookie settings: Always, Never, From Visited:

[image]

I'm from the program to determine which of these modes is enabled as follows: (Never and From Visited)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to check with JavaScript whether the browser has cookies set. Right?

If so, then a really good way of knowing it is to test it.

**Simply set on cookie and then see if you can get it back on your next request. That will tell you what you want.**

---

**ADDENDUM**

If the user chooses not to accept any cookies or delete them within 1 day, there is nothing you can do through you code. That is on your user. If he/she does not want to save cookies then they should not complain about your product because i.e the automatic login or the autofill will not work.

Comment: This test I can not distinguish these settings (Never, From Visited). That is why have difficulty.

Comment: That would be very unreliable, the code should not be able to change or read this kind of private settings...that is what I think

Comment: No, my application depends on these settings should issue an appropriate message. If "From visited", then the application is restarted and all will be ok, and if " Never "it returns an error message